# how to rotate framelayout in is Own axis android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

For academic work I have make a circle with the objects in it and I need to turn it around. 
I made it to a FrameLayout.
But the rotation turns from the edge of the circle and I need it turns from the   middle.
I Would appreciate help

This my code:

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.imageviewlayout);
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fl, "rotation", 0,360);
```

Comment: bit lost to as what you want. perhaps a sketch on paint would supplement this problem well as how it is, and how you want it to be

Comment: I cant display an image but I will try to explain better.

Comment: I have Franelayout holding objects inside a circle and the fishs in it.
this circle should turn around. But at the moment he turns around it does not turns  on is own axis .
I published the way it did.